# Convert a epoch timestamp to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm

Tags: python, datetime

I'm given a timestamp (time since the epoch) and I need to convert it into this format:

`yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm`

I looked around and it seems like everyone else is doing this the other way around (date to timestamp).

If your answer involves `dateutil` that would be great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using `datetime` instead of `dateutil`:

```
import datetime as dt
dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

An example:

```
import time
import datetime as dt

epoch_now = time.time()
sys.stdout.write(str(epoch_now))
>>> 1470841955.88

frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_now).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
sys.stdout.write(frmt_date)
>>> 2016/08/10 15:09
```

**EDIT**: `strftime()` used, as the comments suggested.

Comment: This doesn't put the output in the specified format, OP should use `strftime`

Comment: Worked! Yes, it's not 100% where I need it to be but I think I can manage from here

Comment: @DominikGeorge It got rejected, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @DominikGeorge, usually non-typo edits to code are rejected.  In those cases its best to write a comment to the poster or write your own answer

Comment: @NickBull One other thing is that OP should know that this is specifically in UTC. It might be worth mentioning that they can attach `pytz.UTC` to `dt`, then use `dt = dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')` or whatever time zone they want to convert it to the local time, if they don't just want it in UTC.

Comment: Hmm, ok… I didn't imagine that also counts for plain wrong answers.

Comment: @DominikGeorge, check out this [FAQ post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code) on when you should edit code in questions and answers