# Python unix timestamp not converting but seems value

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have Python source in trying to convert Unix timestamp  to a readable form. My time stamp of 1523620800000 converts to 05/17/2018 @ 5:10pm (UTC) which is valid according to https://www.unixtimestamp.com. Here is my Python code which results in this message:

```
file "xxx.py", line 415, in xxx
    frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
ValueError: year 50251 is out of range
```

The code sample:

```
frmt_date = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")
```

Came from       [Python - Convert a epoch timestamp to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876907/python-convert-a-epoch-timestamp-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm)

What do you think I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: I am getting `1523620800000 Is equivalent to: 08/16/50251 @ 12:00am (UTC)` on https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: Yup, remove the last three zeros and you get a date from April this year.

Comment: I think you need to start with `1523620800` which resolves to `Friday, 13 April 2018 12:00:00`

Comment: When you looked at unixtimestamp.com and got 05/17/2018 @ 5:10pm (UTC) you were looking at the left side of the page that gives the current timestamp.  Look at the right side for the results.

Comment: It appears that your timestamp source is in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Thanks to all for itching the wrong timestamp value. That what was messing everything up so big thanks to those who noticed it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

with this timestamp i get 08/16/50251 @ 12:00am (UTC) from https://www.unixtimestamp.com, and error that is given says that year 50251 is not in datetime